# In c# how do i print a string in the same line, replacing the string each time i print the result?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to simulate a loading screen that goes from 0% to 100%.

I'm using Console.Write instead of WriteLine but this only prints the value alongside the rest instead of replacing the last print.

```
for (int k = 0; k <=100; k++){
                    Console.Write($"[LOADING: {k}% ]");
                    Thread.Sleep(25);
                }
```

This results in:

[LOADING 1%] [LOADING 2%] [LOADING 3%] [LOADING 4%] [LOADING 5%]

I expect a single string that replaces itself with the next printed value

Comment: you need to clear the previous write, because what you doing is simply appending text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call Console.Clear() in each iteration of the for loop to write over any text that was previously displayed in the console.

```
for (int k = 0; k <=100; k++){
                Console.Clear()
                Console.Write($"[LOADING: {k}% ]");
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }
```

Comment: Great idea, it worked as intended. Thanks a lot

Comment: @PedroContreras If it's what you were looking for, go ahead and accept my answer.  Welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: ¡Thanks Luke! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int k = 0; k <=100; k++){
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
                Console.Write($"[LOADING: {k}% ]");
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }
```

Comment: This works but it prints the value atop the screen, i actually need it below other strings printed and do not know the exact position.

Comment: try this Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);

Comment: This worked too, Thanks Alexandr :)